# Mean field theory of classical system of charged particles in presence of external magnetic field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, mean-field-theory

Suppose, there is a system of charged particles interacting via a pairwise additive potential and in the presence of a position dependent external potential  and an external magnetic field. The Hamiltonian of the system can be written as :

$$H = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{(p_i-qA_i)^2}{2m}+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N} V(|\textbf r_{i}-\textbf r_{j}|)+\sum_{i=1}^{N}U(\textbf r_i)$$.

Can anyone give any idea of how to construct a mean field theory of this model ? In Ising model the mean field theory predicts phase transition. Does the mean field theory of the classical charged particle system under consideration also predict phase transition ?

In the Ising model there is no kinetic energy term in the Hamiltonian. But the charged particle system under consideration contain a kinetic energy term in the Hamiltonian. How does it affect the construction of a mean field theory of this system ?

Comment: Isn't that what plasma physics is all about, at least for the potential being a conventional 1/r electrostatic term?

Comment: Yes. But can you outline the process and how does it differ from the ising model

Comment: In the Ising model the spins are on a lattice. In a plasma they are not. You are putting a kinetic energy term in... so I am curious how that makes sense with lattice model, unless you are talking about vibrations?

Comment: That may resemble  a special type of plasma called complex plasma where charged particulates ( micrometer sized ) are injected into plasma and they can form crystal structures.

Comment: So you are asking about magnons in such structures?

Comment: I don't have any idea about magnons. Can you please explain or refer me to some text ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145027/discussion-between-bubucodex-and-flattermann).